# Azure WebApp - Tomcat shutdown

Tags: java, tomcat, azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

I have some Azure Java WebApp.
"Newest Tomcat 8" is the application container that we use.
The option "Always On" is enable for our web app.

Every day tomcat shutdown gracefully:

```
17-Dec-2015 07:07:32.867 INFO [Thread-114] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-1170"]
17-Dec-2015 07:07:32.976 INFO [Thread-114] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
```

When we do the first access in our applications tomcat automatic startup

```
17-Dec-2015 09:45:47.802 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 498942 ms
```

this happen every day.

has anyone else encountered this issue?
How i can prevent tomcat to shutdown?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We resolve the issue.
our application was configured to redirect all traffic to https.

The problem was that the alwaysOn service not following the redirect to https and stop working at web servers layer without ping the application layer.

we change the rewrite URL to no redirect the https to tomcat default root application, which will result in Worker/Java Process to be up all the time as a result of AlwaysON ping

Answer (score 2):

As I known, It seems to be not the Azure issue. If you were enable the option `Always On` for your webapp, Azure would not unload the webapp if webapp was idle for some period of time.

Here is the description for the option `Always On` in the Azure offical document https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/.

> **Always On**. By default, web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources. In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable Always On to keep the app loaded all the time. If your app runs continuous web jobs, you should enable Always On, or the web jobs may not run reliably.

However, the issue would be caused by some case like incorrectly handle exceptions.

As reference, there is an answered thread ([Tomcat randomly shuts down with an AbstractProtocol pause after mild usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088193/tomcat-randomly-shuts-down-with-an-abstractprotocol-pause-after-mild-usage)) explained this issue. You can try to review it and check your issue.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for the response. We resolve the issue.
our application was configured to redirect all traffic to https.

The problem was that the alwaysOn service not following the redirect to https and stop working at web servers layer without ping the application layer.

we change the rewrite URL to no redirect the https to tomcat default root application, which will result in Worker/Java Process to be up all the time as a result of AlwaysON ping

Comment: @bollicino Thanks for the reply.